# .ashx web service connection with swift 2

Tags: asp.net, web-services, swift2, nsurl, ashx

I know very little about Swift 2 and know even less about web services but I have to use them both. I have an ASP web service link which ends with .ashx. I need to connect this web service and post a variable and get list of json objects. When I go to the link with web browser, this text is shown:

[image]

I tried a sample code but I could not figure out how to send parameter to web service and it give a "Could not serialize" error.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let urlString = "http://bla.bla/bla.ashx"
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!

    session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if let responseData = data {

            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)

            } catch {
                print("Could not serialize")
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Actually I can not find how to begin searching. Is there a tutorial that you can suggest me? Thank you!

Comment: You're trying to download *this HTML page* as if it was JSON. But it's not, it's HTML. The instructions are telling you to send a *query* with some code, and *this* in turn will send back JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Eric, it helped me to understand more clearly. I auto generated Objective C code by entering http://bla.bla/bla.ashx?OBJC link to web browser (I could not figure out how to use OBJC query string, that is it) and a sample code for my web service connection has been downloaded. Now it is time to convert objective C code to swift 2.